# What is the SPWebService and how does it fit into the hierarchy?

Tags: architecture

I'm trying to understand the SharePoint hierarchy of objects and don't understand SPWebService .

Here is what I have:

- SPFarm contains

  - One or (usually) multiple WebApplications, each contains

    - One or more SPSites which then contain one or more SPWebs

I know that each SPWebApplication can have one or more SPContentDatabases and that SPSite is really a child of a Content Database which is really a child of SPWebApplication.

It looks like the SPWebService sits between SPFarm and SPWebApplication, but I don't understand if there is always just one or if there can be multiple SPWebServices? And under what circumstances would someone have more that one SPWebService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPWebService is a container for the SPWebApplications.

For instance You can use the `SPWebService.ContentService` static property to return the SPWebService object which contains all content web applications (the `SPWebService.AdministrationService` can be used to get the web app for CA).

Comment: Ah great, that solves another issue that I had, "how to get the Farm Admin Site?". Do you know if there can ever be more than 1 SPWebService in a Farm?